# Ruby: Compare two arrays for matches, and order results in DESC order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user model. Each user has restaurant names associated with them. I have a view (index.html.erb) which shows all users.

I want to order the users in this view based on how many restaurants the current_user and some other user have in common in descending order... (it does the opposite!)

---

ex.

User1 (current_user) has been to McDonalds, Burger King, Arby's

User2 has been to Ivar's

User3 has been to McDonalds, Burger King

---

When User1 loads the index view, the order the users should be displayed is:

User1 (3/3 restaurants match)

User3 (2/3 restaurants match)

User2 (0/3 restaurants match)

---

my User.rb file

```
def compare_restaurants
  self.restaurants.collect
end
```

my users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.all.sort_by {|el| (el.compare_resturants & current_user.compare_resturants).length }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're dead set on using `sort_by` then you can just negate the numbers:

```
def index
  @users = User.all.sort_by { |el|
    -(el.compare_resturants & current_user.compare_resturants).length
  }
end
```

This trick only works because you're sorting by numeric values. If you were sorting on strings then you'd have to use something like this:

```
reverse_sorted = a.sort_by { |x| something(x) }.reverse
```

but that would involve an extra copy of the array and the extra work that `reverse` would do. In such cases you should use a full `sort` with reversed comparison logic.

If you're were  trying to use `sort_by` to avoid computing something expensive for each comparison and you were sorting on something non-numeric, then you could always use `sort` with an explicit [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to compute the expensive things only once.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort them in the controller.

```
my = User.find_by_id this_user  # Or however you're getting "the current user"
@users = User.all.-([my]).sort do |a, b|
  common_with_a = (my.restaurants & a.restaurants).length
  common_with_b = (my.restaurants & b.restaurants).length
  common_with_a <=> common_with_b
end
```

... but if you're planning on letting the user start sorting various columns or reversing the sorting a lot, you should implement your sort in Javascript so you can cut down on the number of page reloads and subsequent database hits you have to make.

Comment: @echoback Thanks for your response, however I get "cant convert my into array.."

Comment: Replace the last line with `common_with_b <=> common_with_a` to reverse the order.

Comment: is it not possible to order by desc using ¨sort_by"?

Comment: @odpogn: If your `sort_by` is numeric then you can just negate the values to reverse the sort order, otherwise you can use `.reverse` after the `.sort_by` or just use `.sort` and reverse the comparison logic.